# Objective-CでNSDataからPCM8bitへの変換方法について

Tags: objective-c

サーバーからソケット通信で受け取った800バイトの音源データ（PCM8bit8khz）を再生したいのですが、現在解決に至っておりません。
AVAudioPlayerのinitWithdataを使えば良いのではと思い以下のコードを動かしてみたのですが、

```
//関数の呼び出しaudioDataは受け取ったデータ
[self prepareAudio:audioData];

〜


//デリゲートメソッドなど
-(void)prepareAudio:(NSData*)data
{

    self.player.delegate = self;
    NSError *error = nil;

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data fileTypeHint:AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat error:&error];

    if ( error != nil )
    {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [self.player prepareToPlay];


}

#pragma mark - AVAudioPlayerDelegate
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    if ( flag )
    {
        NSLog(@"Done");
//        [self.playButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // Can start next audio?
    }
}
```

**Error 操作を完了できませんでした。（OSStatus エラー 1954115647。）**

と表示されてします。（どうやらAVAudioで読み込めない形式というエラー？）
AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormatをいろいろ変更してもだめでした。

Androidでは以下のコードで動いているため、

```
bufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
        8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);
audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        8000,  //[Hz]
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, //[bit]
        bufSize, //[byte]
        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
audioTrack.play();

〜〜〜

// soundByteが音声データ
audioTrack.write(soundByte, 0, soundByte.length);
```

こちら側で変換してやる必要があると思い、Core Audioを用いた変換を試していますが現在試行錯誤している段階です。

http://objective-audio.jp/2008/03/core-audio-audiostreambasicdes.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioConverterNew

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription wavFormat;
wavFormat.mSampleRate = 8000.0;
wavFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
wavFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked; //WAVの8bitはunsigned
wavFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 8;
wavFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
wavFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
wavFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 1;
wavFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 1;
wavFormat.mReserved = 0;
```

800k8hzなので、上記のようなAudioStreamBasicDescriptionかなと思ってますが、上記をどのように利用するのかでつまずいております。

ご教示いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 上記ですが、送られてくるデータがwavファイルでしたので、下記URLをもとにヘッダーを付け加えることで解決できました。
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021528/ios-float-buffer-to-audio-playback